# Преобразование таймзоны даты с сохранением прежней структуры вывода

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, datetime

Есть такой код: 
`counterFinallyData._date = new Date(date);`

Который на выходе дает результат, при занесении его в базу данных:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стоит задача изменить тайм зону вывода времени - попробовал реализовать это через следующую команду:
`counterFinallyData._date = new Date(date).toLocaleDateString('ua-UA', { timezone: 'Europe/Kiev'}` );

Но получил результат в виде преобразованной строки(что логично, исходя из команды.)
`_date: "13.03.2007"`

Вопрос:
Как изменить UTC - сохраняя структуру вывода в базу т.к. это отображено в первом результате?

Comment: Ничего не понятно.

Comment: Что именно не понятно в вопросе?
(это самый простой вопрос, который только может быть)
Как поменять UTC - сохраняя обьектную структуру данных в выводе в базу.
Как это показано в первом результате.

Comment: (что бы она не была строчной и была идентичной с первым случаем)

Comment: Непонятно: какие входные данные? Что ты ожидаешь в выходных? Дату или строку? Если дату, то часовой пояс не принадлежит дате в js. Если строку, то чем не устраивает полученная? И при чём тут вообще база данных? Стоило бы [mcve] показать. И вообще, у тебя сервер в часовом поясе UTC?

Comment: Входные данные если уж лезть так глубоко(не знаю зачем) - это CSV - тайм зона UTC+2
В процессе парсинга этого файла данные почему то становятся на сколько я понимаю UTC-0.
Мне необходимо сделать их идентичные на выходе в базе с изначальным CSV в плане тайм зоны.